# How to save last-child in variable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I need to save `last:child` `img` element in variable how can I do this ?

```
<div class="main-img">
    <img src="img/images/12.jpg">
    <img src="img/images/12.jpg">
    <img src="img/images/14.jpg">
</div>
var zom = $('.zom');
var bg = $('<div class="bg-zoom"></div>');
var zomed = $('.main-img img:last-child').clone().addClass('slider-zoomed');

zom.on('click',function(){
    $('.content').append(bg);
    bg.append(zomed);
});
```

Comment: is this what you want? var myvar = $('.main-img img:last-child').get(0)

Comment: What do you mean by img element?

Comment: You could also go $('.main-img img').eq(-1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var zom = $('.zom');
var bg = $('<div class="bg-zoom"></div>');

zom.on('click',function(){
// I only need  $('.main-img img').last(); and works fine
var zomed = $('.main-img img').last().clone().addClass('slider-zoomed');

    $('.content').append(bg);
    bg.append(zomed);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

JQuery has a .last() function.

http://api.jquery.com/last/

Comment: show  how to use .last()  like  $('.main-img>img').last()

Comment: @ScottSelby `alert($(".main-img img").last().attr('src'));` will return `img/images/14.jpg` [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df210cn4/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant source...

```
var lastImg = $('.main-img img:last-child').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the HTMLImage element. You can get it from your jQuery object using [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) function:

```
var imgElement = $('.main-img img:last-child').get(0);
```

or

```
var imgElement = $('.main-img img:last-child')[0];
```